# Bind data from a different controller in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding

In angular 4.

I have navbar, a menu component with different tasks. This task comes from a web service.

When I click on one of these task from the menu, it calls the **edit task** component, with a form on it.

The data from the form of the edit task is bind to some fields from the component of Edit task, so when I change something in the form, it is reflected in the header of the form.

But the data from menu component don't change. **How can I update/bind the data in the menu component?** I don't want to refresh the page. Maybe the solution is calling the  getTasks() function, but that have to be done in the **edittask** component

**menu.component.ts** here i call the list of tasks:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getTasks();
}

getTasks(): void {
    this.taskService.getTasks()
        .subscribe(Tasks => this.tasks = Tasks);
}
```

**menu.component.html**  here i call the task list:

```
<li *ngFor="let task of tasks" class="d-inline-block col-md-12">
    <a routerLink="/task/{{task.id}}" > {{task.title}}</a>
    <!-- <span class="close big"></span> -->
    <button class="close big" title="delete task" (click)="delete(task)">x</button>
</li>
```

after filling the form from the edit task I call the function onSubmit() for call the webservice:

```
this.taskService.updateTask(task, id)
      .subscribe(
        // i need to refresh the getTask that is in the menu. 
        // or do something for update the menu task
        );
```

Comment: Hey, did either of the answers help you? :)

Comment: @AJT_82 no, I re-ask the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913150/how-to-detect-change-from-one-component-into-other), and found an answer:

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subject to tell the menu component to refetch the data, so in menu component declare a subject and listen to any `next`:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

// ...

public static updateTasks: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

constructor(...) {
  MenuComponent.updateTasks
    .subscribe(res => {
       this.getTasks();
    })
}
```

and then in the component where you edit the task, just call `next` on the subject to tell the menu component to execute `getTasks`:

```
import { MenuComponent } from '....'

// ...

this.taskService.updateTask(task, id)
    .subscribe(() => MenuComponent.updateTasks.next(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add Detect change in your menu component ?

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {

    this.cdRef.detectChanges();

}
```

And import :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

and add this to constructor param :

```
private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef
```

Comment: I did it, but nothing happens. @LéoRoueire