# How to detect change from one component into other

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

Angular 4. [Github source](https://github.com/josuevalrob/tasks/tree/master/src/app)

I have a menu which is filled by a web service. The web service is in taskService, but is not necessary now.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getTasks();
    }
    getTasks(): void {
        this.taskService.getTasks()
            .subscribe(Tasks => this.tasks = Tasks);
    }
```

When you click on a task it loads a page, a different component, with a form ready to update the data. It is also made by a web service and works fine. **The problem is that after update the task, it is not reflected in the task menu**

I am importing this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

and adding this to the constructor:

```
private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef
```

And this is my best approach to the detectChanges() function, **after update the data with the save() function**

```
  this.taskService.updateTask(task, id)
          .subscribe(
              this.Ref.detach();
              setInterval(() => {
                this.Ref.detectChanges();
              }, 5000);
      );
```

**This is the html from the menu to print the tasks:**

```
   <li *ngFor="let task of tasks" class="d-inline-block col-md-12">
        <a routerLink="/task/{{task.id}}" > {{task.title}}</a>
        <!-- <span class="close big"></span> -->
        <button class="close big" title="delete task"
        (click)="delete(task)">x</button>
    </li>
```

**And this is the form that updates the task**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="save(taskName.value, taskBody.value)" #taskForm="ngForm" class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <label>Task Name</label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="task.name" #taskName name="name">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput [(ngModel)]="task.body" #taskBody name="body"></textarea>

  </mat-form-field>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Save</button>
</form>
```

Both are in different components.

I have tried to follow this [tutorial](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detach), but I'm stuck, I don't know how to use the ChangeDetectorRef.

Comment: Can you post your html file too?

Comment: done @BunyaminCoskuner

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you would need to trigger `changeDetection` manually. Angular should be able to pick it up when you update `tasks`. Do you set `changeDetectionStrategy` in your `Component` declaration?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `this.tasks` in your subscribe callback is being redefined with the updated data from the form submission?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner no, nothing of that, i have to it manually, cuz they are in different components. Look here is the full [project:](https://github.com/josuevalrob/tasks/tree/master/src/app)

Comment: Oh, okay now I see the problem. I'll try to come up with a solution.

Comment: After running the `updateTask()` in the view.task component, I did a `console.log` there, in the menu component, to see if something change, but no, my console log show me old data.  @bazzells

Comment: Ok so after `updateTask()` finishes, it's returned to `save()` in your `ViewTaskComponent`, but there is no link to `this.task` in the subscription callback to `this.taskService.updateTask()`. Since `updateTask` uses a PATCH request, I'm assuming you're not getting the whole `Task` object back. So you won't be able to just say `this.task = valuePassedToSubscribeCallback`. Instead you can invoke `this.viewTask()` in that subscribe callback and fetch the entire updated `Task` object.

Comment: @ValRob I posted a possible solution. Check it out.

Comment: thanks @BunyaminCoskuner i will test it now!

Comment: where to I put the invoke `this.viewTask()` ? in the `save()` function, inside the `updatetask`? @bazzells

Comment: Yup. Just think of it as the following flow: (1) submit form (2) make PATCH request (3) fetch updated data _once_ PATCH finishes. Only place to know PATCH has finished is inside the callback for the subscription to `updateTask`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've looked at your code. The problem is that the `view-task.component` updates your tasks, but the `navigation.component` is not notified about this transaction. I think `BehaviorSubject` might be just the thing for you.

You can read more about it [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#behaviorsubject)

I assume you would have single array of `tasks` throughout your application and you would display them on your `navigation` component.

Task.service.ts

```
export class TaskService {
     // behaviorSubject needs an initial value.
     private tasks: BehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject([]);
     private taskList: Task[];

     getTasks() {
         if (!this.taskList || this.taskList.length === 0) {
             this.initializeTasks();
         }

         return this.tasks.asObservable();
     }

     initializeTasks() {
          this.http.get('api/tasks')
              .subscribe(tasks => {
                   // next method will notify all of the subscribers
                   this.tasks.next(tasks);
              }, error => {
                   // proper error handling here
              });
     }

     updateTasks(task: Task) {
          this.http.post('api/updateTask')
              .subscribe(resp => {
                   // update your tasks array
                   this.tasks = ...
                   // and call next method of your behaviorSubject with updated list
                   this.tasks.next(this.tasks);
              }, error => {
                   // proper error handling here    
              });
     }
}
```

Navigation.component.ts

```
 export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit{
      tasks: Task[];
      constructor(private taskService: TaskService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
          // this method will be called every time behaviorSubject
          // emits a next value.
          this.taskService.getTasks()
              .subscribe(tasks => this.tasks = tasks);
      }
 }
```

View-task.component.ts

```
 export class ViewTaskComponent {
     constructor(private taskService: TaskService) {}

     updateTask(task: Task) {
         this.taskService.updateTask(task);
     }
 }
```

I haven't tried this code myself. However, I have implemented something similar on my application before. So when you try it and have a problem, let me know.

Comment: I have a diferente get http request, it give a problem: `initializeTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {
      const url = `${this.mainUrl}/tasks`;
     const returnGets = this.http.get<Task[]>(url)
            .subscribe (tasks => {               
                   this.tasks.next(tasks);
              });
      return returnGets
   }` Said that the type **'subscription'** is not assignable to type **`'observable<Task>`'**. Property `'_isScalar'` is missing in the subcription

Comment: You are defining your return type as `Observable<Task[]>`, but you are subscribing to the http request. If you want to return an Observable, you cannot subscribe to it. If you just want to get the data and assign it to some attribute, you should subscribe to it but can not define your return type as `Observable`. You should do one thing or the other.

Comment: Okay, thanks it works, but with a couple of things different: [service.ts](https://github.com/josuevalrob/tasks/blob/master/src/app/task.service.ts) ,
 [view-task.ts](https://github.com/josuevalrob/tasks/blob/master/src/app/view-task/view-task.component.ts) and the [navitation.ts](https://github.com/josuevalrob/tasks/blob/master/src/app/navigation/navigation.component.ts).

Comment: This is my `updatetask()` now:

    `updateTask (task: Task, id){
      const url = ${this.mainUrl}/node/${id};        
      return this.http.patch(url, task, httpHaljson)
          .subscribe(resp => {
            this.initializeTasks()
          });
    }`

Comment: I'm glad it works, just one final note. You don't need to return `Subscription`, probably no one is gonna do anything with it

Answer (score 3):

Angular isn't running `changeDetection` because you aren't asking it to. None of the instance variables in your `ViewTaskComponent` are being updated inside your `save` method.

In your code, after `updateTask()` finishes, it returns to `save()` in your `ViewTaskComponent`. But there is no link to `this.task` in the subscription callback to `this.taskService.updateTask()`.

Since `updateTask` uses a PATCH request, I'm assuming you're not getting the whole `Task` object back. So you won't be able to just say `this.task = valuePassedToSubscribeCallback`.

Instead you can invoke `this.viewTask()` in that subscribe callback and fetch the entire updated `Task` object.

For example:

```
this.taskService.updateTask(task, id)
    .subscribe(
        // new line here to fetch the updated Task object
        this.viewTask()
    );
```

Note: I'd second @Bunyamin Coskuner's suggestion to utilize `BehaviorSubject`'s (or even a standard `Subject`). If you're up for a refactor, they are a clean way to manage state within your services.

Comment: I dont know how to log this, but i got an error `StaticInjectorError[NavigationComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NavigationComponent!`

Comment: That's thrown because on line 32 of view-task.component.ts you've initialized your `NavigationComponent` private variable in your class. You shouldn't need to though. Is there a reason you have that in there? Try commenting it out at least and seeing if it runs.

Comment: done, but it doesn't work. I don't get anything after `save()` function. :(

Comment: Are you referring to the `NavigationComponent` not updating? In order for that to work I'd recommend implementing a `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`.